# drupal_set_message not working on one specific template?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have one specific template which `drupal_set_message()` does nothing on. The `$messages` are printed out in a header include which also exists on this template. I've triple checked that it's using the template I think it is, etc.

The only difference I can tell between this and any other page template I'm using is that this is a node-specific template. Specifically `page-node-170.tpl.php`.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the custom template (page-node-170.tpl.php) has the following lines somewhere visible:

```
<?php if ($show_messages && $messages): print $messages; endif; ?>
<?php print $help; ?>
```